# can't play video on default player on Nexus 7

Tags: android

> I am using android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW but i am not able to play video on default player

```
File file = new File("fileUri");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Do you get any error? If yes,then post your error trace.

Comment: ERROR :- android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=/storage/emulated/0/.MYDATA/QBVIDEO_1415617477011.mp4 typ=video/* flg=0x10000000 }

Answer (score 0):

First make sure if device has **working default player**.

And if it's there setting mimetype in intent will help like this. And make sure to add **read_external_storage** Permission.

```
public static Intent getVideoIntent(String fileUrl) {
    Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    videoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileUrl)), getMimeType(fileUrl));

    return videoIntent;
}

public static String getMimeType(String url) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);

    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(type))
            type = "video/*"; // No MIME type found, so use the video wildcard
    }

    return type;
}
```

Comment: so your device may not having default player.

Comment: i have default player